# How do I parse a nameless array with different types using Jackson

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson

I have some json data that looks like

```
"value": [ 1572553480.732, "118" ]
```

And the parser is choking with a "Cannot construct instance of Value (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no double/Double-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (1.572553780732E9)"

My data class looks like:

```
public class Value {
  private double uTime;
  private String count;
  public Value() { super(); }
  public Value(double uTime, String count) {...}
  // also getters and setters for both
}
```

Comment: Perhaps a custom [de-serializer](https://dzone.com/articles/custom-json-deserialization-with-jackson) will get you out of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@JsonFormat` annotation with `JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY` shape:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JsonPathApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String json = "{\"value\": [ 1572553480.732, \"118\" ]}";
        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, Root.class));
    }
}

class Root {

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
    private Value value;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Root{value=Value{uTime=1.572553480732E9, count='118'}}
```